# How to show only house ads using admob?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I've created the test app on AdMob site. Also, add my own small banner there. Get the id of app and banner and insert into code. But in the application I see other ads, not mine. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please add how this is related to Unity?  is you app developed in unity?  Or are you using only a preview thing to see how your add would look?  What exactly are you trying to do with admob?  for example are you developing an app and only what to see your ads on your app? we need a bit more detail on whats going on, because the way this is worded hundreds of things can be going on... or it could be a simple misunderstanding on exactly what you think admob is for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display only in house ads, you should create your campaign and use theese params : 
- **Campaign type** : Percentage of traffic
- **Percentage of traffic** : 100

Put also a high **CPM** (like 500) to be sure only your ads are displayed.
Maybe it's not the right way to do it, but it's how i am doing it and it works well.

Then select **self-promotion** and **no cap on impression** (for the Frequency capping) and you should be good.

Comment: This used to work for me but iPhone X it seems it doesnt work anymore.  Maybe banner size?

Comment: It works for a while then stops within weeks or months. Creating a new campaign is the only thing that works.